# How to derive the hydrostatic equilibrium equation from the variational principle?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, astrophysics, fluid-statics, variational-principle, equilibrium

I was reading the book "Advanced Stellar Astrophysics" (William K. Rose, 1998) and I came across a different approach to deriving the hydrostatic equilibrium equation. First he defined the total energy of a static, spherical star,
$$
E = \int udM - \int \dfrac{GM}{r}dM, \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
where $ u $ is the internal energy per gram. Then he defined the Lagrangian change in the internal energy density,
$$
\Delta u = u(r + \xi(r)) - u_0(r),
$$
where $ \xi(r)$ is the Lagrangian displacement and $u_0(r)$ are the undisturbed values of the internal energy density.  The next step is completely strange and doesn't make much sense to me: He makes a Lagrangian variation in \eqref{1} and looks like:
$$
\Delta E = \int \Delta u dM + \int \dfrac{GM}{r^2}\xi(r)dM \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
which he calls,
$$
\Delta u = - P\nabla\bigg(\dfrac{1}{\rho}\bigg) = \dfrac{P}{\rho^2}\Delta \rho
$$
How did he arrive at these last two results? I can't deduce that $r^2$ in the denominator of the second term of the equation \eqref{2} and neither the positive sign.

Comment: Hint: Substitute $r \to r + \xi(r)$ and subtract from original equation. Remember $\xi(r) \to 0$

Comment: Thank you! got here doing this and then expanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am missing why this proves what it is intended to prove, but I can certainly fill in your missing details.

So the claim is that we examine a perturbation$\delta r$ which is very very small and for any other quantity we define $\delta F = F(r + \delta r)-F(r)$ to first order.

We insert it in every single term in the integral (this is the part which I find suspicious) and have
$$\delta E =\int\mathrm dM\left(\delta u - \frac{GM}{r+\delta r} + \frac{GM}{r}
\right).$$
To answer your first question, the middle term satisfies
$$\begin{align}
- \frac{GM}{r+\delta r} &= -\frac{GM}r \frac1{1+\frac{\delta r}r}\\
&= -\frac{GM}r \left(
1 - \frac{\delta r}r + \left(\frac{\delta r}r\right)^2 -\dots
\right)
\end{align}$$
by the usual rules of geometric series. To first order we keep the first two terms only.

Second there is the claim that $$\delta u = - p~\delta V,$$a standard claim of thermodynamics which again just sort of doesn't make sense here but that's because I don't see exactly what the argument is. Since $u$ is the internal energy per unit of mass then $V$ should be the volume per unit of mass, which makes it exactly $V = 1/\rho$ where $\rho$ is the mass density. Doing a Taylor series $$\delta\frac1\rho =-\frac{\rho'~\delta\rho}{\rho^2}$$ to first order.

I think I can make sense of this but I do not think I can make sense of this inside of that integral sign which I would want to rewrite as $$\int \mathrm dM =\int  \rho(r)\mathrm dr$$ and then I would never do a Lagrangian path variation on $r$ but on $\rho$ maybe. I spent a little time trying to Google ways to do thermodynamics as a sort of calculus of variations problem, and got a lot of black hole thermodynamics papers which figures. I suppose one could try to maximize the entropy or so, maybe minimize a free energy assuming that the core of the star is held at a very constant temperature or so, argue that the density profile which minimizes this should be the quasi-static equilibrium? But again, varying $r$ just sounds like you are doing a fancy version of the normal, “balance two forces against each other” argument and this integral over $\mathrm dM$ is spurious?

Comment: That was exactly what didn't seem to me to make any sense. I followed a path similar to that suggested by the book to prove that the star's hydrostatic equilibrium state corresponds to a stationary point in relation to the total energy. To do this, I tested the idea of ​​disturbing the star in an adiabatic, but arbitrary and infintesimal way. After some manipulations and boundary conditions, come the expression of the variation of the gravitational potential energy, which you kindly derived.

Comment: And it worked! In the end it appeared that in order for the condition for hydrostatic equilibrium to be recovered we must have to, $$\dfrac{dP}{dM(r)} = - \dfrac{GM(r)}{4\pi r^4}.$$ which is precisely the Lagrangian version of hydrostatic equilibrium!